# Springboot @Retryable include multiple exceptions

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-retry

I have put the **@Retryable** on the interface method and now I need to include more than one exception to retry.

Code:

```
 @Retryable(interceptor = "someRetryInterceptor",
        include = { SomeException.class, SomeOtherException.class })
```

Is this a correct way to do it?

Note: In `someRetryInterceptor` I have defined the RetryPolicy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to javadoc interceptor  is mutally exclusive with other attributes.
So you must decide to use either interceptor or include.

But to be sure: **Just unit-test it!**
 make your method with `@Retryable` annotation throw `SomeException` or `SomeOtherException` and see it.

One of ways to test it: 
Assume you are retrying method

```
void dummy() {
 someObject.someOperation();
}
```

Mock `someObject`  (using Mockito or any other library) so that `someOperation` will throw S`omeException/SomeOtherException`.  In test verify number of invocations of someObject.someOperation()

If you have infinite retries (that is rarely usefull) then test will hang, so such test must have timeout (`@Test(timeout=1000)`) and you must make test pass when `TimeoutException` occurs.

If you have finite number of retries, then you should verify how many times `someObject.someOperation()` was invoked before timeout.

Note: that test must be Spring test (must load context with `@EnableRetry` annotation). Otherwise (if you write it as plain unit test) then `@Retryable` annotation will be completly ignored.

Comment: All of the configuration has to be done on the `interceptor` when specified; other properties on the annotation are ignored.

Answer (score 3):

No; when you specify an `interceptor`, all of the configuration has to be done there (including the exceptions handled by the `RetryPolicy`).

See the javadocs:

```
/**
 * Retry interceptor bean name to be applied for retryable method. Is mutually
 * exclusive with other attributes.
 * @return the retry interceptor bean name
 */
String interceptor() default "";
```